# How do I send files on my PC to the computers at my school through bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh

I need to send files the are on my PC the computer system at my school. In order for me to log in a manipulate the files on my school profile (when using bash) I have to type :

```
ssh -Y <username>@<school_name>.com
```

And that works just fine. But what I'm wondering is, if I want to be able to manipulate a file (for example file.txt) that is on my PC, how would I be able to send and manipulate the file.txt at school?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not Unix technical support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `scp <file> <username>@<school_name>.com` from your PC's terminal. For futher details goto this link: [SCP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles)

Comment: I suggest to add `:` after `<username>@<school_name>.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [SCP](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

It allows you to copy a file on your local machine to a remote machine (such as your school computer) of vice versa.